# yii 1.1 db transaction and auth extension

Tags: php, pdo, yii, transactions, yii-extensions

I used yii auth extension (http://www.yiiframew...extension/auth/) and tried to implement DB transaction (CDbTransaction). Below is my code and it is working fine when I develop it and test it using superadmin.

```
public function actionUnpost($id) {
    if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $qtyCheck = array();

        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction(); // Transaction begin

        try {
            // If unpost this will resulting in negative remaining quantity, we should cancel this unpost!!!
            foreach ($model->formDetails as $detail) {

                if (isset($qtyCheck[$detail->id])) {
                    $qtyCheck[$detail->id] -= ($detail->quantity * $detail->type);
                } else {
                    $qtyCheck[$detail->id] = Journal::model()->getRemReceivingQty($detail->id, $detail->locationFk) - ($detail->quantity * $detail->type);
                }

                // remaining has normal balance positif, so check the remaining should not be less than 0
                if (0 > $qtyCheck[$detail->id]) {
                    throw new CDbException('Stok barang ' . $detail->item->name . ' menjadi negatif, FB tidak bisa diunposting!');
                }

                // Delete journal entries
                foreach ($detail->journalEntries as $entry) {
                    $entry->delete();
                }
            }

            $model->postingStatus = FormHeader::UNPOSTED;
            $model->save(false);

            $transaction->commit();
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "FB $model->headerNo telah berhasil diunposting.");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    } else {
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again!');
    }
}
```

But when I created other users with limited permissions, this code failed to work. The transaction is not working, I could not understand why. I have to move the commit to above positions to make it work.

```
            $transaction->commit();

            $model->postingStatus = FormHeader::UNPOSTED;
            $model->save(false);

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "FB $model->headerNo telah berhasil diunposting.");
```

It does not make sense to me. With the bottom code, the purpose of transaction will not be satisfied.

I used mysql innodb for the tables and should not be any problem with pdo or whatsoever, since it is work fine when the user is superuser.

FYI, I also use audittrail extension (http://www.yiiframew...on/audittrail2/).

Any help with this?

PS: ERROR message
PDOException
There is no active transaction

```
/home/xxx/projects/framework/db/CDbTransaction.php(80)

68            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbTransaction is inactive and cannot perform commit or roll back operations.'));
69     }
70 
71     /**
72      * Rolls back a transaction.
73      * @throws CException if the transaction or the DB connection is not 
active.
74      */
75     public function rollback()
76     {
77         if($this->_active && $this->_connection->getActive())
78         {
79             Yii::trace('Rolling back 
transaction','system.db.CDbTransaction');
80             $this->_connection->getPdoInstance()->rollBack();
81             $this->_active=false;
82         }
83         else
84             throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbTransaction is 
inactive and cannot perform commit or roll back operations.'));
85     }
86 
87     /**
88      * @return CDbConnection the DB connection for this transaction
89      */
90     public function getConnection()
91     {
92         return $this->_connection;
```

Comment: what exception are you getting

Comment: See question at the bottom, too long to be added here..